# Consumer producer problem with directories

Tags: c, concurrency, pthreads, semaphore, producer-consumer

im implementing a program in C which uses the consumer producer problem and im encountering a segmentation fault error. Basically i have 1 producer thread and N consumer threads, the producer thread has to search recursively through my file system and add directories to the buffer.

The consumer threads take one element from the buffer and check if within those directories exists a file with a given name. Im using 2 semaphores  and 2 mutexes to solve the problem. The problem is that after some work the program either blocks or gives a segmentation fault error and i can't find the problem.

Variables used:

```
void *recursive(char *diretorio,int indent);

//array of directories (buffer)
char *diretorios[20];

//consumption semaphore
sem_t sem_consumir;

//semaphore for producing
sem_t sem_produzir;

int prodptr=0, consptr=0;

//consumption mutex
pthread_mutex_t mutexCons;

//producing mutex
pthread_mutex_t mutexProd;
```

Producer code:

```
void *produtor()
{
    char * diretorio="/home/user";
    recursive(diretorio,0);

}


void *recursive(char * diretorio, int indent)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    int i;
    int value;

    if (!(dir = opendir(diretorio)))
        pthread_exit(NULL);

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR)
        {
            char path[PATH_MAX];
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;
            snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", diretorio, entry->d_name);
            printf("%*s[%s]\n", indent, "", entry->d_name);

            sem_wait(&sem_produzir);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexProd);
            diretorios[prodptr]=strdup(path);
            prodptr=(prodptr+1)%10;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexProd);
            sem_post(&sem_consumir);

            recursive(path, indent + 2);

        }
    }

    closedir(dir);
    //pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Consumer code:

```
//consumer code
void * consumir(MYFIND_DATA * data)
{


    char fullpath[PATH_MAX + 1];
    char *path;


    while(1)
    {
        char * diretorio;
        DIR *dir;
        struct dirent *entry;
        int value;
        //existe um diretorio para consumir

        sem_wait(&sem_consumir);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexCons);
        diretorio = diretorios[consptr];
        consptr = (consptr+1) % 10;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexCons);
        sem_post(&sem_produzir);
        // }

        if ((dir = opendir(diretorio)) != NULL )
        {
            if(Findname(diretorio, data->nome))
            {

                printf("FILE ENCONTRADO: %s em %s\n", entry->d_name);
                data->ocorrencias++;
            }

            //read directory entries
            while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
            {


                if (strcmp(entry->d_name,".")!=0
                        && strcmp(entry->d_name,"..")!=0 )
                {
                    //look for a match
                    if(Findname(entry->d_name, data->nome))
                    {


                        printf("FILE FOUND: %s\n", entry->d_name);
                        data->ocorrencias++;

                    }

                }
            }



        }



    }
    printf("acabou o produtor");
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Main function code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    struct sigaction action;   
    action.sa_handler = signal_handler;
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);

    sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);

    int t;
    pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];
    pthread_t ttid;
    pthread_t tid_state;
    MYFIND_DATA data[NUM_THREADS];

    sem_init(&sem_produzir,0,10);

    sem_init(&sem_consumir,0,0);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexCons,NULL);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexProd,NULL);


    //create producer thread
    pthread_create(&ttid, 0, &produtor, NULL);

    //create consumer thread
    for (t = 0; t<1; t++)
    {
        data[t].nome = "worksheet";
        data[t].ocorrencias=0;
        pthread_create (&tid[t], 0,(void *)consumir, &data[t]);
    }


    pthread_join(ttid, NULL);


    for (t = 0; t<1; t++)
    {
        pthread_join (tid[t], NULL);

        printf("\nThread %d joined, ocorrencias = %d",t, data[t].ocorrencias);
    }

}
```

When i run the program this is the result:
[program running in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJbEi.png)

I already checked and the producer does it's job filling the array, i think the problem lies when it runs out of directories to produce but i'm not sure. Any ideia what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does the consumer check if there are any entries in the queue?

Comment: @stark the consumer just grabs one of the entries from the queue, he doesnt check if there are any. It basically trusts that the producer is doing it's job filling the buffer. Even if its null it will jump out in the if condition

Comment: Where does the producer set empty values to null?

Comment: Where is closedir in the consumer?

Comment: Run your program in the debugger. You will see immediately _where_ the segfault happens.